# How to get password value in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7, hook

I trying to get password value without a hash in `hook_user_presave()`, and I can do that easy when create user, I just get it in `$account` variable. But when I edit user, pass in `$account` in hash to because `$account` data getting from database. So how i can get plain password value?

Here is my hook:

```
function hook_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
    if (isset($account->pass)) {
        $edit['field_clean_pass']['und'][0]['value'] = $account->pass;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing that requires the password in plain text? Are you sure the user is actually entering the password in the form that you are saving? If they are not entering the password, there is no reasonable way to get the plain text version of the password, because it is not stored at all...

Comment: the admin need to see user password, because he can be able to enter as any user in database...

Comment: The plain text password is not saved in the database, only the hashed and salted version of it is.

Comment: It is highly not recommanded oO

Comment: i know its not recomendated and not safety, but i need do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) module?

If admin needs to be logged in as any user this module is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer... you can always try that module that allows site owners to get readable passwords: https://www.drupal.org/project/aes

Comment: hm, i get the next error `PDOException: in function field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (строка 451 in file /var/www/drupal/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).`

Comment: Did you read the project page entirely and install the dependencies? When this error occurs?

Comment: sure, i enabled mcrypt php5 module but how you can see it no results